# How to make images scroll one after other

Tags: jquery, html, css

Below is the code i have implemented. I want to make the image scroll one one box after another. Like image below i mean the 4 images should be scrolled from right -> left by scrolling with speed.sorry in the below image i have mistakenly done 2 images but i want 4 image to scroll right -> left.Is there any way to do this css? or jquery 
[image]

```html
       
                                          <div class="empsliderwrap" style="">
                                                  <div class="empslidermain clr"><div class="clr"></div>          <style>
      .logosliderwrapnew{overflow:hidden;}
      .logoslidernew{width:100%;overflow:hidden;height:auto;}
      .logosliderinnr{width:999px;height:auto;}
      .logoslideritem{width:300px;height:auto;}
     </style>


                               <div class="logosliderwrapnew">
                                      <div class="logoslidernew" style="position: relative; height: 480px;">
                                             <div class="logosliderinnr"><div class="logoslideritem lft" style="position: absolute; left: -300px;"><div class="emplogorow clr"><a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/M0cP1m9.jpg" alt="TCS   IT Jobs in India" title="TCS   IT Jobs in India"></a>
<a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/Hdc3XSr.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
<div class="emplogorow clr"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/QQpUNAc.jpg" alt="Jobs at Larsen &amp; Toubro" title="Jobs at Larsen &amp; Toubro"></a>
<a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/izye7CS.gif" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
<div class="emplogorow clr"><a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/t3hOOIG.jpg" title="Jobs at Larsen &amp; Toubro"></a>
<a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/nnNPuSw.gif" alt="Tech Mahindra- IT Job opportunities" title="Tech Mahindra- IT Job opportunities"></a>
</div>
<div class="emplogorow clr"><a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/uyEO4Hb.gif" alt="Wipro- IT Job opportunites" title="Wipro- IT Job opportunites"></a>
<a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/M0cP1m9.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>




</div>
</div>
<div class="logoslideritem lft" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;"><div class="emplogorow clr"><a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/M0cP1m9.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
<a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/QQpUNAc.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
<div class="emplogorow clr"><a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/izye7CS.gif" alt="2147483649" title="2147483649"></a>
<a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/t3hOOIG.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
<div class="emplogorow clr"><a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/t3hOOIG.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
<a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/Hdc3XSr.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
<div class="emplogorow clr"><a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/uyEO4Hb.gif" alt="" title=""></a>
<a href="" class="emplogo lft" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="135" height="50" src="http://i.imgur.com/izye7CS.gif" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `marquee` tag

`<marquee direction="right"><img src=""><img src=""><img src=""><marquee>`